# Opencart 3 filter products

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special";

    if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p";
    }

    //FILTRU
    $sql .= " INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value ovi ON (p.product_id=ovi.product_id)";

    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ";

    //FILTRU
    if (isset($this->request->get['option_value'])) {
        foreach ($_GET['option_value'] as $key => $value) {
            $sql .= " AND  ovi.option_value_id='$value'";
        }
    }
```

Where is FILTRU there I insered a code to view in category only products with option_value selected in browser. If i select only one option, it works, but when i have more than 1 option she doesn't select anything.

How i can do to select all products with more options?

All products have minimum 3 option_values.

Comment: Well, you have a lot of mixed logic both database and server-side - i would recommend create stored procedure in mysql and then parse data

Comment: This code is part of a function to get all products and this function is called by many page. I can't modify the sql sequence, only to add conditions like          
                   if (isset($this->request->get['option_value'])) {
        foreach ($_GET['option_value'] as $key => $value) {
            $sql .= " AND  ovi.option_value_id='$value'";
        }
    }

Comment: (assuming that you're developing/testing on your computer and not on a live site) You could temporarily add an "echo $sql;" at the end to output the SQL to see what's actually being asked of the database/debug the query.